# Implementing "Sign Up/Register," when CRUD methods are protected with @Check('admin')?

Tags: security, playframework, authorization, crud

I have a simple application using the Play! framework's secure module.  My 'Users' controller extends CRUD and is protected by @Check('admin'), so users have to be admins to access CRUD methods.  However, I'd like anyone to be able to create new Users-- like a "Sign Up" or "Register" button.

What is a good way to do this, given that all of my Users methods except Create should be protected?  Can I apply @Check("admin") to individual methods?

Here is my Users controller:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

@Check("admin")
@With(Secure.class)
public class Users extends CRUD {
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is a good way to do this, given that all of my Users methods except Create should be protected?**

> In my practice, I create new controller in another package with the same name for doing this.
>
> For example,
>
> [image]
>
> So, I think the best way is you should put Sign up method in the Non-Admin.
>
> After I find some reference, [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/eec8c54980f3a31a) has same idea with you and the answer of this topic is like what I said.

**Can I apply @Check("admin") to individual methods?**

> Yes, you can. But you need to use @With(Secure.class) in that controller first.
> You can see the example in [Secure Module Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/secure).